# How to check unchecked boxes in nested loop (Selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, nested-loops

Stuck on how to check unchecked boxes in Selenium, in regards to company sub categories. Created a nested loop and experimented with different syntax.. still not getting it. Tried to set xpath equal to True..didn't work either. run code and lmk what you think !

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

#navigate crunchbase & add parameters
addcolumn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator add-column-button mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary"]')
addcolumn.click()

compcats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mat-list-item")

subcats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("checkbox")

uncheck = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-checked="false"]')

for cc in compcats:
    for sc in subcats:
        if uncheck.is_displayed():
            sc.click()
```

Updated Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

#navigate crunchbase & add parameters
addcolumn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator add-column-button mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary"]')
addcolumn.click()

# get items only from first list
all_categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[1]//mat-list-item')
print('len(all_categories):', len(all_categories))

for category in all_categories:
    print('-----')
    
    # select category
    print('Category:', category.text.strip())
    
    # scroll it to make it visible and clickable
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", category)
    # or
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(category).perform()
    
    # click category to display list of columns in this category
    category.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # search columns ONLY in selected category

    # it selects item only if `mat-checkbox` doesn't have class `mat-checkbox-checked`
    # and it click `label` instead of `checkbox` because `label` is not hidden by `popup message`
    columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
    print('len(columns):', len(columns))

    for col in columns:
        print('click:', col.text.strip())
        col.click()
    
    # TODO: click subcategory, select checkboxes, click back button 
    subcategories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-list-item[.//icon[@key="icon_caret_right"]]')
    print('len(subcategories):', len(subcategories))
    for sub in subcategories:
        sub.click()
        
        subcolumns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[3]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
        
        for subc in subcolumns:
            subc.click()
            
    backbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-dialog-1"]/column-panel/div/dialog-layout/div/mat-dialog-content/div/div/div[1]/button')   
    backbutton.click()  
        
        
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Apply Changes"]').click()
```

Tried continue, break, and pass statements but just not understanding the `backbutton` code logic now i.e. where it goes & and how to only run it after the last iteration of checked subcategories...

Comment: I didn't run code but `click()` may change HTML in browser and it may need to use again `xpath` to get elements in new HTML.

Comment: I didn't run code but your for-loop make no sense for me. You always use `driver.` to search `compcats`, `subcats` so they get all items on page and using nested loop make no sense. It would make send if you would use relative path inside some item - like `cc.find_...` instead in `drive.find_...` to search only in one `comcat`. Maybe frist you should use `print()` to see what you get at this moment you runs many time loop for the same elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.

First: you try to get all checkboxes before loop but you should get only all categories, next run loop to click category and then search checkboxes for current category, and for every checkbox you should search `checked`

Second: this page displays non-standard widgets so it doesn't change `checked` in `checkbox` but set class in some non-standard widget.

There was also other problem. When I clicked `category` or `checkbox` then sometimes it was displaying `popup message` which was hidding other `checkbox` and code couldn't check it. I click `label` which also check `checkbox` but it doesn't display `popup message`

In two categories there are subcategories and it still needs code which will click subcategory, get checkboxes and check them. And next it has to click button to go back to categories.

---

There are many `//mat-nav-list` - one with categories, one with columns and subcategories and one with columns in subcategory - so I have to use index to work with correct list - and xpath starts indexes at `1` - `(//mat-nav-list)[1]`, `(//mat-nav-list)[2]`. It needs also `( )` to select correct list because `//mat-nav-list[1]` and `(//mat-nav-list)[1]` mean different objects.

---

Minimal working code:

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

#driver path
#PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#access crunchbase ui
driver.maximize_window()  # it is more natural (for human) to resize window before opening page - and some servers may check window size to detect script.
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

#navigate crunchbase & add parameters
addcolumn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator add-column-button mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary"]')
addcolumn.click()

# get items only from first list
all_categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[1]//mat-list-item')
print('len(all_categories):', len(all_categories))

for category in all_categories:
    print('-----')
    
    # select category
    print('Category:', category.text.strip())
    
    # scroll it to make it visible and clickable
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", category)
    # or
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(category).perform()
    
    # click category to display list of columns in this category
    category.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # search columns ONLY in selected category

    # it selects item only if `mat-checkbox` doesn't have class `mat-checkbox-checked`
    # and it click `label` instead of `checkbox` because `label` is not hidden by `popup message`
    columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
    print('len(columns):', len(columns))

    for col in columns:
        print('click:', col.text.strip())
        col.click()
    
    # TODO: click subcategory, select checkboxes, click back button 
    subcategories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-list-item[.//icon[@key="icon_caret_right"]]')
    print('len(subcategories):', len(subcategories))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Apply Changes"]').click()
```

Comment: should I write a for loop for subcategories inside of of the 'columns' for loop ?

Comment: not inside `for col` loop but directly after `subcategories = ...`. And it will to `click` every subcategory, and use `xpath` to search `subcolumns` (probably in `(//mat-nav-list)[3]`) and loop to click subcolumns, and finally it will need to clik button to go back to categories.

Comment: Ahhh...got it. For future reference how could I discover what number an element is indexed at ? For Example: ```(//mat-nav-list)[2] & (//mat-nav-list)[1]```

Comment: I uses DevTools in Firefox/Chrome to see elements in HTML. They have also function to find element by xpath - ie. shortcut `Ctrl+F` or `F3`. If I use `//mat-nav-list` then it shows that there are 3 elements and it highlight first element - if I press F3 then it highlight second element, etc. I also run Python code with `[1]` and display results to see what it gives, next I do the same with `[2]`, etc.

Comment: ok great. so I go thesub category for loops to work (updated code above) I just am not understanding how to finesse what to do with the backbutton if you could take a look...

Comment: You use this button in wrong place - you have to click it inside `for sub` (after checking all subcategories) but you click it in every loop (even if you don't have subcategories)